# ReentrantReadWriteLock vs synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

When should we use *ReentrantReadWriteLock* as compared to *synchronized* keyword in multithreaded environment in Java?

What are the benefits of using *ReentrantReadWriteLock* over *synchronized* in Java?

Can any one give an example as well (in Java)?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read this thread and then see if there is a better way to word your question, as which is better will depend on what you are doing, how your code is accessing objects/variables. http://forum.ragezone.com/f683/synchronised-vs-reentrantlocks-696540/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Synchronized allows in one thread at a time.

Read/Write locks allow in multiple readers a the same time, but only if no writers are already in. Hence under some usage scenarios we can get better concurrency, because the reader populations can proceed together.

Java API [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) gives the example of collection classes which are expected to have more readers than writers.

Answer (score 17):

The [locking article by Brian](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809031812/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/) explains in detail the pros and cons of each approach.

> The Lock framework is a compatible
> replacement for synchronization, which
> offers many features not provided by
> synchronized, as well as
> implementations offering better
> performance under contention. However,
> the existence of these obvious
> benefits are not a good enough reason
> to always prefer ReentrantLock to
> synchronized. Instead, make the
> decision on the basis of whether you
> need the power of ReentrantLock. In
> the vast majority of cases, you will
> not -- synchronization works just
> fine, works on all JVMs, is understood
> by a wider range of developers, and is
> less error-prone. Save Lock for when
> you really need it. In those cases,
> you'll be glad you have it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that [`StampedLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) has since come out with Java 8, and it's much faster than `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (especially as you use more and more threads) when you don't use the lock in a reentrant manner (using `StampedLock` reentrantly can lead to deadlocks, so don't do it).

It also allows optimistic read nonlocks that are available if there is no write lock in effect. Unlike a normal read lock, they don't block a write lock from being established. You can check whether a write lock has been established over your optimistic read nonlock by using [the `validate` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html#validate-long-).

Its interface is a little different since you have to store a `long` value called a stamp in order to later unlock a read or write lock properly or to later `validate` an optimistic read nonlock properly when you're done.